# Cannot get two sections next to each other without screwing up other things

Tags: html, css

What I have:

I have a header section and a body section (class="header" class="body" respectively) and inside the header section I have a logo section and a menu section. I am trying to put the logo and the menu on the same line.

What I tried:

Floating one left and the other right. Results in background disappearing for the header section. changed the width of logo to 20% and menu to 80% and them floating them left and right. Same results as the above. Tried display:inline which results is a big mess.

Is it possible to get the two sections next to each other without messing up something else?

Also can someone explain what is wrong ans why is it?

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eZaWK/1/

Relevant html

```
<body>
    <section class="header">
            <section class="logo">
                <a href="#"><img src="logo.png" height="50px"/></a>
            </section>
            <section class="menu">
                <ul id="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">About ￬</a>
                        <ul class="hidden">
                            <li><a href="#">Who We Are</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">What We Do</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </section>
    </section>

    <hr>

    <section class="body">
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        <p>Hello world</p>
    </section>
</body>
```

Relevant CSS

```
body{
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #46a7bb;
}

.header{
    width:100%;

}

hr{
    border-color:black;
    border-bottom-width:5px;
    margin:0 0 0 0;
}

h1{
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

.body{
    width:75%;
    margin:auto;
    background:white;
    text-align: center;
}

.logo{
    margin:0;
    background: #313145;

}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add the following rule:

```
.header, .logo, .menu{
    float: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4v2nZ/

Comment: THe background for the header section disappears as can be seen in the jsfiddle you linked

Comment: it disappears because the background color css was applied to '.logo', not to '.header'. updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4v2nZ/1/

Comment: Ah I see. By the way will it be possible to float the menu towards right but keep the logo to the left?

Comment: I tried changing the width of the logo section and it emulated floating right. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: yes, delete from 'ul' style `position:absolute` and put `.menu{ float: right; }`. also add `.hidden{ position:absolute; }` so that your menu does not knock off anything on hover. i've updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4v2nZ/3/